# Open and update an existing workbook with 2 worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

This may be simplistic to most of you. I just started using VBA to create and update excel workbooks. I found some code on the internet to open and update an existing workbook and worksheet. Like I said, I am brand new at this.  Does this code even make sense? I just need to know how to open an existing workbook and all the examples I have found aren't working in our environment.Thanks for any help I can get

```
Dim wbSource, xlApp, srcWorksheet 

 'initialize
 Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

 'open source and target files
 Set wbSource = lApp.Workbooks.Open("X:\GCIXCycleCompare_test_auto.xlsx")
 set srcWorksheet = wbSource.Worksheets("NewCycle")
 srcWorksheet.sheets("NewCycle").Activate

 srcWorksheet.Rows("1:1").Delete
```

Comment: Not sure if it's a typo here, but you want `Set wbSource = xlApp...` not just `lApp...`.  Also, you're doing `Set srcWorksheet = ...`  which sets it as a woksheet. The next line you just need `srcWorksheet.Activate`, calling the worksheet again may result in an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Excel VBA, this isn't quite what you want.  This code was written for an external app (say written in VB6) to open Excel remotely and then do stuff to that copy of Excel.  If you are already in Excel/VBA you obviously don't need to do that.

In VBA, the equivalent code would be something like this:

```
Public Sub MyCode()
    Dim wb as Workbook
    Dim ws as Worksheet 

    Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open("X:\GCIXCycleCompare_test_auto.xlsx")
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("NewCycle")

    ws.Rows(1).Delete
End Sub
```

If you run this code (by click F5 from inside VBA ... or by run macro in Excel) it should open up the test file off the X: drive, and then delete the first row of it.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to remotely access an excel spreadsheet and update the existing data on a specific sheet ("NewCycle")

Comment: But do you want to open a separate copy of Excel from the copy that is running your VBA?

Comment: Like I said. This is all new to me. I am learning as I go. This is the situation. We have an excel spreadsheet sitting on a server that, up to now, has been manually updated. I am writing a batch job that I submit to a processor that finds the excel sheet, opens it, updates it, closes it and ends. Thats the basic scenario I am faced with. I appreciate your help. I don't know if you have accessed an excel spreadsheet in this manner.

Comment: Ok.  So you have a copy of Excel already open with your VBA code in it.  Then what I said is true.  The "CreateObject" line in your code was telling your VBA code to open a *second* copy of Excel and do stuff with that.  That is almost never what you want.

Comment: No worries.  It's always hard to get started...  I wrote this kind of code for 22 years...

Comment: If you have a separate Executable (say running a VB6 program or Access or something else) you would use CreateObject to open a copy of Excel to do your work...

Comment: This spreadsheet was created manually using micrsoft excel. Each week we copy sql tables into it to manually update it. Now I want to automate that process by extracting sql tables into .dat files and reading this data into one of the 2 spreadsheets. I was just experimenting trying to access and update an existing spreadsheet using a batch job. I don't know if this is a process that many people out there use now or not.

Comment: Sure... This kind of office automation code is very common.

Comment: The code I showed you at the beginning was part of a program I used to combine separate spreadheets into a single workbook and it already works. I was hoping to use that concept to open a workbook and update it.... but I don't know if I am mixing apples and oranges here. I am a 30 year cobol programmer trying to catch up to modern technology